# Unable to insert into sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have tried to  insert values into sqlite database but it shows me an error stating unable to insert the values to the database no such table is found.Even i have tried changing the database vaersion and uninstall the app and installed it again but it didn't works.

Database:

```
public class BuisnessDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "receiptExample";

// Labels table name
private static final String TABLE_LABELSS = "buisnesslabels";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String KEY_STATUS="status";
private static final String KEY_UPLOADSTATUS = "uplaodstatus";
private static final String KEY_USERID="userid";
SQLiteDatabase db;
public BuisnessDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Category table create query
    String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELSS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB, "
            + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_UPLOADSTATUS + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_USERID + " TEXT" + ");";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELSS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
public void insertLabel(byte[] imag,String status,String uploadstatus,String userid){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(KEY_ID,id);
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE,imag);
    values.put(KEY_STATUS,status);
    values.put(KEY_UPLOADSTATUS,uploadstatus);
    values.put(KEY_USERID,userid);
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LABELSS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
public ArrayList<BuisnesslistItems> getAllLabels(){
    //  List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<BuisnesslistItems>labels=new ArrayList<BuisnesslistItems>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELSS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            BuisnesslistItems buisnesslistItems=new BuisnesslistItems();
            buisnesslistItems.setImage(cursor.getBlob(1));
            buisnesslistItems.setStatus("Status:"+cursor.getString(2));


            labels.add(buisnesslistItems);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}

public String composeJSONfromSQLite(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> label;
    label = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM buisnesslabels where " + KEY_STATUS + " = '"+"no"+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(cursor.getBlob(1), Base64.DEFAULT);
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_ID, cursor.getString(0));
            map.put(KEY_IMAGE, encodedImage);
            map.put(KEY_USERID,cursor.getString(4));
            map.put(KEY_STATUS,"yes");
            label.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    database.close();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    //Use GSON to serialize Array List to JSON
    return gson.toJson(label);
}

/**
 * Get Sync status of SQLite
 * @return
 */
public String getSyncStatus(){
    String msg = null;
    if(this.dbSyncCount() == 0){
        msg = "Wallet is Sync with cloud!";
    }else{
        msg = "Wallet needs to be Sync\n";
    }
    return msg;
}

/**
 * Get SQLite records that are yet to be Synced
 * @return
 */
public int dbSyncCount(){
    int count = 0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM buisnesslabels where " +KEY_STATUS+" = '"+"no"+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    count = cursor.getCount();
    database.close();
    return count;
}

/**
 * Update Sync status against each User ID
 * @param id
 * @param status
 */
public void updateSyncStatus(String id, String status){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String updateQuery = "Update buisnesslabels set " + KEY_STATUS + " = '"+ status +"'," + KEY_UPLOADSTATUS + " = 'Uploaded' where " + KEY_ID + "="+"'"+ id +"'";
    Log.d("query", updateQuery);
    database.execSQL(updateQuery);
    database.close();
}
public void deleteUploaded(String status){
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String deleteQuery="Delete From buisnesslabels where " + KEY_STATUS+ " = 'yes' ";
    Log.d("dquery",deleteQuery);
    database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
    database.close();
}
```

Even i have another table in the same database but it works fine i don't know why it is getting a error like this.

Error:

```
06-16 11:09:14.681  16067-16067/nidhinkumar.reccs E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting uplaodstatus=waiting to upload status=no userid=7 image=[B@3f20a44d
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: buisnesslabels (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO buisnesslabels(uplaodstatus,status,userid,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1499)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1371)
        at nidhinkumar.reccs.buisnesscarddetails.BuisnessDatabaseHandler.insertLabel(BuisnessDatabaseHandler.java:70)
        at nidhinkumar.reccs.buisnesscarddetails.Buisnesscardmain.uploa(Buisnesscardmain.java:358)
        at nidhinkumar.reccs.buisnesscarddetails.Buisnesscardmain.onOptionsItemSelected(Buisnesscardmain.java:343)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2940)
```

Comment: Uninstall app and run

Comment: i have done it but it didn't works

Comment: `SQLiteException: no such table: buisnesslabels`. But I cannot understand how, when you're creating that table beforehand.

Comment: Try manually deleting the database on startup for once:
mContext.deleteDatabase(MyDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME);